# Filter the DataTable on the basis of array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a **DataTable** `dtEmployee` with one of the column is `EmployeeId`.

I have an array of Integers with. I have to find all the values of array , that are not there in `EmployeeId` column of **DataTable** `dtEmployee`.

Comment: @palak When you ask the question always post the piece of code or whatever you tried for solution.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)

```
List<int> empIds = new List<int>(); //your employee Ids List

List<int> resultList = empIds.Except(dtEmployee .AsEnumerable()
                                       .Select(r => r.Field<int>("EmployeeID"))
                                       .ToList()).ToList();
```